# How does sklearn randomforest predict probabilities for multi label classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have implemented [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) from sklearn library to solve a multi-label classification problem. After having fitted the model, the predictions (done with predict_proba of sklearn) compared to the target values in the test set look like this:

```
y_target : [1,    0,  0,  0,  1,    0, 1,    0]
y_predict: [0.98, 0,  0,  0,  0.93, 0, 0.4,  0]

y_target : [0,    0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0,    1   ]
y_predict: [0.36, 0.08, 0.03, 0.44, 0.68, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03]
```

The model performs well, however, I don't understand how these probabilities are created. For each class, it predicts the probability of the class to be 0 or 1 instead of calculating the probability among the classes. Because when you look at y_predict, the summation is much greater than 1. Does it create a random forest for each class separately and then calculate the probability per class with a fraction of the vote?

Important to note is that my input X has 41 features and output Y is a one-hot encoded vector of size 8. The settings I use for the model are shown below:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                      bootstrap=True,
                      max_depth=None,
                      max_features='sqrt',
                      random_state=None,
                      min_weight_fraction_leaf = 0,
                      class_weight='balanced')
```

I hope someone can help me to clarify this.

Comment: Try it without One-Hot Encoding the y value.